# Upload multiple files in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, multi-upload

The **Image Field** only allows one file at a time to be uploaded. Is there a module that enables multi-upload in Drupal 7?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Comparation of upload modules:
http://groups.drupal.org/node/155764

I use this modules:
[Multiupload Filefield Widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget)

and for images
[Multiupload Imagefield Widget](http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_imagefield_widget)

Comment: Out of curiosity, Why cant we add "multiple" attribute to input file tag? Why Drupal complicates it more?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to upload multiple files per node, you can edit the image field settings to allow that. Go to Home » Administration » Structure » Content types » [Content type] » Manage fields then edit the Image field.

If you want to upload multiple files at once, it looks like [Plupload](http://drupal.org/project/plupload) is your only real option. Or you could use [FileField Sources](http://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources) to attach images that have been uploaded via FTP.

Comment: Thanks! I will check them out.

Answer (score 1):

You may try File Resumable Upload
https://www.drupal.org/project/file_resup

> **File Resumable Upload** aka **file_resup** adds large files multiple and
>   resumable upload to the *File* and *Image* field widgets.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this modules : http://drupal.org/project/multiupload_filefield_widget

Or also  http://drupal.org/project/custom_add_another.