# Drupal bulk file upload

Tags: drupal, file-upload, drupal-7

I have created a content type and the contents submitted in this content type is displayed to client using views with lightbox.

Content type has got a file field  element in the form to upload the file in pdf format.Thus each upload is saved as a node.

I have got around thousands of such pdf files that to be uploaded and displayed in the front end using lightbox .

Is there any possible method to upload the pdf in bulk (say some 30 to 40) rather than uploading one by one?

Please suggest.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7206531/upload-multiple-files-in-drupal-7

Comment: Thanks  BaikHo  for a quick response. I am concerned about the number of pdfs to be uploaded not the multiple upload option in the content type.I just want to know if there is any bulk import of files (say few hundrends in one go each stored as a node) possible just as we do for other data using CSV import/feeds import etc?

Comment: Are you aware there's a Drupal-specific StackExchange? http://drupal.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for the Drupal specific StackExchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not aware of a current Drupal solution, but if I was in your situation, I'd probably upload the files en masse using another upload method, then import them in a batch with a bit of custom code to rip through the contents of the directory, associate the files and maybe create notes or entities as appropriate.

Uploading even thousands in batches of 30-40 sounds like an enormous waste of your time when such a thing could be done in a single task if you write the code to do it up front.

(I don't have a code example sorry, but there was a module to do this in Drupal 6: [File Import](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_import).)

Comment: Ya true , will check by developing a custom module for this purpose referring the file import module.

Comment: Another angle with looking at is Migrate module. Might be a bit to get your head around at first but there is an example (WineFileCopyMigration) which does basically this.

Comment: Migrate module seems a better option, need to analyze.Thanks Chris